# How to create a prompt

Tags: c, linux

Is there any way to create a prompt like `"#"` at the terminal before the user's typing,after "type something"? Without using `printf("#");`

```
 char str[500]; 
 printf("type something"); 
 scanf("%s",&str);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use `printf`?

Comment: Just looking if there is a way. @pzaenger

Comment: Why is `printf("type something")` okay but not `printf("#")`?

Comment: He's asking for an alternative to that...why don't people just answer someone's question or move along? Every question I read on here...rude, ignorant comments but nothing constructive is offered... OP try putchar()

Comment: Have you looked at the [c tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info)? (Try searching for "Hello World")

Comment: So the question is reduced to "how to print a character without `printf`".

Comment: I would have thought that `printf("type something")` is better than `printf("#")` anyway. You, or someone else, runs your program in 6 months time and it prints `#`. What the heck does that mean?

Comment: I want both `printf("type something")` and the `#` symbol. Like terminal gives `$` @WeatherVane

Comment: `printf("type something\n#")`

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a function that asks for an input while displaying a prompt. Analogous to `read -p "#' input` in bash.

Comment: And without using `printf`... @WeatherVane
I think my question is quite clear...

Comment: Exactly! This is what i am looking for. @alvits

Comment: Why not make your own function to do it? What is the objection to `printf`? Why is `putchar` OK but not `printf`?

Comment: @WeatherVane The whole story sounds like a joke, the same thing for the given Answer of using `putchar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following

```
putchar('#');
```

Comment: Is there any reason why he should use `putchar` instead of `printf ?` I'm just asking. Anyway this should be a comment and not an Answer, because there is no explanation why.

Comment: I thought he wanted `#`.